# Can I keep animated text in PowerPoint from going outside its text box?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I have a PowerPoint slide with a few text boxes in it. I'd like the text in one of those boxes to animate, scrolling up, as you'd see in movie credits.

I can get the text to animate that way, but when text reaches the top of the text box, it just keeps scrolling up, so you see the words leave the text box and float up past the other text boxes. By the time it ends, I have the words from the animated text box sitting on top of the words from the other text boxes.

Is there any way to constrain the animation so it the text disappears as it reaches the top of the animated text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following gif. You could use **Send to Back** function.

[image: 1]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!